# How do the two different force formulae ($F = ma$ and $F = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$) relate to each other?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity

$F = ma$ and $F = G\frac{m_1m_2}{r^2}$ are two formulae. Aren't they measuring the same thing? How do they relate to each other?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it doesn't show enough previous effort.

Answer (score 4):

This is an *extremely* good question despite its seemingly simple nature. It connects everything from Newton to string theory to debunking moon landing conspiracies. I'm surprised that the question has '-1' points at the moment (before I upvoted it to make it $0$!).

The concepts surrounding it have a long history involving people from [John Philoponus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Philoponus) to Galileo, Einstein, Steven Weinberg, Neil Armstrong and even string theorists like Polyakov. The ideas have been discussed in the context of Newton's gravity, Einstein's formulation of general relativity, modifications to general relativity and string theory. They have also undergone various, far-reaching, high-precision experimental tests.

Newton's second law says that a force ($F$) exerted on an object causes it to accelerate ($a$) with the resistance offered to this acceleration being decided by what is called inertial mass ($m_i$):

$$F = m_i a$$

Newtonian gravity says that the gravitational force ($F_g$) experienced by an object depends on the gravitational potential ($\phi$) and its gravitational mass ($m_g$):

$$F_g = -m_g \nabla \phi$$

That $m_i = m_g$, is an empirical fact and/or motivated by deep physical principles. $m_g$ is a measure of how a body reacts to an external gravitational field and is of a different nature than $m_i$. It might very well be the case that $m_i \neq m_g$.

Newton's empirical observation that pendulums of equal length but different masses have the same time period lead to the idea that all objects are affected by gravity identically. Galileo was also instrumental in similar experimental observations, concluding that different bodies undergo free fall identically. These developments lead to the idea that $m_i = m_g$, such that all bodies have the same acceleration under free fall. This idea was that of a universal nature of gravity: that every object (irrespective of its composition/mass) falls at the same acceleration rate in a gravitational field. If $m_i \neq m_g$ then different bodies fall at different rates.

The idea of equating inertial mass with gravitational mass was taken many steps further by Einstein with the advent of the [Equivalence principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equivalence_principle). There are various versions of the equivalence principle, most commonly known ones being the Weak, Einstein and Strong equivalence principles: WEP, EEP and SEP, respectively.

1) WEP states that $m_i = m_g$ and therefore, all bodies undergo free fall at the same rate. From the equations of motion, we see that we have a preferred frame, i.e., the free fall frame, where there are no external forces acting on the body. So, locally, being accelerated and being under a gravitational influence have the same physical consequences.

2) EEP states that, in a gravitational field, locally, all non-gravitational laws of physics reduce to that of special relativity.

3) SEP supersedes EEP by including gravitational physics laws in addition to non-gravitational ones.

The [Eötvös experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/E%C3%B6tv%C3%B6s_experiment) is a classical test of the WEP: it checks the equivalence between $m_i$ and $m_g$. The fractional difference in accelerations of different bodies has been measured up to $2 \times 10^{-13}$ according to Ref 1 (page 8).

There is a way to test WEP indirectly through SEP: [Nordtvedt effect](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nordtvedt_effect). See also Nordtvedt's original papers: Refs 2 and 3. If SEP is true, then gravitational self energy should contribute equally to inertial mass $m_i$ and gravitational mass $m_g$. If not, then the difference in $m_i$ and $m_g$ causes different objects to accelerate at different rates, violating WEP. Gravitational self energy is negligible for objects used in laboratory experiments (negligible in the sense that such levels of precision are out of the reach of current experimental limits).

But celestial objects have much larger gravitational self-energies. Nordtvedt proposed an experiment (see Ref 4) to see if $m_i \neq m_g$, using laser ranging to measure the distance between earth and the moon. This experiment is called the [Lunar Laser Ranging experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lunar_Laser_Ranging_experiment). When Apollo 11 astronauts landed on the moon, they placed a [retroreflector](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retroreflector) there to reflect lasers from earth to moon and back to earth for high-precision distance measurements. (Other missions also planted such retroreflectors.) For more information about this experiment, see Refs 5, 6, 7, 8 and 9. If $m_i \neq m_g$, then the 'Nordtvedt term' would cause the orbit of the moon around the earth-moon center of mass to be polarized in the direction of the sun. According to Ref 1 (page 47):

> Numerous ongoing analyses of the data find no evidence, within experimental uncertainty, for the Nordtvedt effect
>
> These results represent
>   a limit on a possible violation of WEP for massive bodies of about $1.4$ parts in $10^{13}$

(For more information about these results, please look at the references cited in the quoted text above in Ref 1, page 47)

In general relativity, $m_i = m_g$ and there is no Nordtvedt effect. This equality may not be true in other theories, for instance, in [scalar-tensor theories](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scalar%E2%80%93tensor_theory) like [Brans-Dicke theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brans%E2%80%93Dicke_theory). In such theories, there is an extra scalar degree of freedom apart from the metric $g_{\mu \nu}$. This can cause problems for the validity of SEP/WEP. See Refs 10, 11 and 12.

Gravity theories with a scalar field also lead to the search for a [fifth force](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fifth_force).

String theory typically predicts a scalar-tensor theory too. The scalar field is called the [dilaton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dilaton). See Refs 13 and 14.

For more information about the various versions of the equivalence principle, please see Refs 15 and 16.

Though we might have to wait a while to test the equivalence principle in different scenarios and with better experimental precision, at least we can be sure that Neil and Buzz *did*, in fact, land on the moon.

[image]

<sup>[Image source](http://www.apolloarchive.com/apollo_gallery.html)</sup>

---

References:

(1) C.M. Will, *The Confrontation between General Relativity and Experiment*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1403.7377

(2) K. Nordtvedt, *Equivalence Principle for Massive Bodies. I. Phenomenology*, https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.169.1014

(3) K. Nordtvedt, *Equivalence Principle for Massive Bodies. 2. Theory*, https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.169.1017

(4) K. Nordtvedt, *Testing Relativity with Laser Ranging to the Moon*, https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRev.170.1186

(5) J. O. Dickey, P. L. Bender, J. E. Faller, X X Newhall, R. L. Ricklefs, J. G. Ries, P. J. Shelus, C. Veillet, A. L. Whipple, J. R. Wiant, J. G. Williams, C. F. Yoder, *Lunar Laser Ranging: A Continuing Legacy of the Apollo Program*, https://doi.org/10.1126/science.265.5171.482

(6) B. Schwarzchild, *Gravitational Self‐Energy and the Equivalence Principle*, https://doi.org/10.1063/1.882880

(7) J. G. Williams, S. G. Turyshev, D. H. Boggs, *Lunar Laser Ranging Tests of the Equivalence Principle with the Earth and Moon*, https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0507083v2

(8) S. Baeßler, B. R. Heckel, E. G. Adelberger, J. H. Gundlach, U. Schmidt, and H. E. Swanson, *Improved Test of the Equivalence Principle for Gravitational Self-Energy*, https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.83.3585

(9) E. G. Adelberger, B. R. Heckel, G. Smith, Y. Su & H. E. Swanson, *Eötvös experiments, lunar ranging and the strong equivalence principle*, https://doi.org/10.1038/347261a0

(10) L. Hui, A. Nicolis, C. Stubbs, *Equivalence Principle Implications of Modified Gravity Models*, https://arxiv.org/abs/0905.2966

(11) T. P. Sotiriou, V. Faraoni, S. Liberati, *Theory of gravitation theories: a no-progress report*, https://arxiv.org/abs/0707.2748

(12) T. Damour and G. Esposito-Farese, *Tensor-multi-scalar theories of gravitation*, https://doi.org/10.1088/0264-9381/9/9/015

(13) T. Damour, F. Piazza, G. Veneziano, *Violations of the equivalence principle in a dilaton-runaway scenario*, https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/0205111

(14) T.R. Taylor, G.Veneziano, *Dilaton couplings at large distances*, https://doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(88)91290-7

(15) E. Di Casola, S. Liberati, S. Sonego, *Nonequivalence of equivalence principles*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1310.7426

(16) E. Di Casola, S. Liberati, S. Sonego, *Weak equivalence principle for self-gravitating bodies: A sieve for purely metric theories of gravity*, https://arxiv.org/abs/1401.0030

Answer (score 2):

The first formula, $F=ma,$ describes the effect that forces have on objects, namely that a force causes an object to accelerate, with larger masses having slower acceleration.

The second formula, $F=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2},$ describes the force generated by the gravitational attraction between two masses a certain distance apart.

In effect, the first formula tells you what forces do, and the second tells you how one kind of force is generated.

Answer (score 1):

$\vec F = m \vec a$ is Newton's second law. It relates the net force acting on an object with the net acceleration produced by those forces. $\vec F = \frac{GMm}{r^2} \mathbf{\hat r}$ is Newton's law of universal gravitation. It tells us the attractive force by two masses towards each other. Since they were both developed by Isaac Newton, they are related, in a sense.

Consider two isolated masses, $m$ and $M$. The gravitational force are the only forces, so the net force also in the same direction. We can thus write $$ ma = -\frac{GMm}{r^2}$$ This is the force experienced by $m$ in a gravitational field of another mass $M$. Note that the negative sign is due to the attractive nature of the gravitational force.

$a$ might thus be better represented as the gravitational field strength, $\vec g = -\frac{GM}{r^2} \mathbf{\hat r}$. This is the force per unit mass (in other words, the acceleration) experienced in a gravitational field - which makes sense, given that we canceled $m$ earlier.

Answer (score 1):

When we use the same symbol for both forces, like here we use $F$ doesn't mean they represent the same thing. The $F$ in Newton's Second law or $F=ma$ represents the **resultant force**(vector sum of all forces which can be of *any* type like suppose gravitational or electromagnetic etc.) in any classical situation, for an object of mass $m$ to suppose calculate its acceleration $a$.

The other formula $F=\frac{Gm_1m_2}{r^2}$ represents a special type of force which is **gravitational force**. It is the force of attraction between objects that have mass. Hence even is symbols are the same it is always important in physics to understand the **context** of the symbols.

Note that these two formulas *can* become equal to each other if the only **resultant force** that is acting is just **gravitational** force. Then only you can write the two $F$s equal to each other.

Answer (score 0):

F=ma describes how a force will affect an object. For example, a force that yo exert to move a book.
The gravitational force formula gives you the force which occurs when two body with mass comes together. That is, it is only one kind of force. It tells you that any two bodies with mass will attract each other.

In contrast, F=ma tells you that the more mass a thing has, the harder it is to accelerate it (or to make it stop moving).

They relate to each other simply by: mg=ma